# Where can I find historical documentation for bash?

Tags: bash, documentation

Are there any sources for documentation for old versions of some GNU software, in this case particularly `bash`?

I have a embedded system that is running bash 3.00.16, and I'm trying to do some shell scripting, and things are not working as expected (no process substitution, apparently).

Furthermore, since this is an embedded system, I don't have `man` or `info`, so there is really no help available on the system.

Is there anywhere I can view the documentation for older versions of `bash` as they were for various releases?

Comment: bash 3.0 had process substitution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49918/when-was-process-substitution-first-introduced/49940#49940. Are you sure you have `#!/bin/bash` and not `#!/bin/sh` for your shebang?

Comment: @jordanm - I was thinking about that. `help` returns `GNU bash, version 3.00.16(2)-release (i486-slackware-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @jordanm - However, `echo <(ls)` returns `-sh: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`. It works on a new machine, though

Comment: @jordanm - aaaarrrrgghhhh, I somehow *wasn't* in bash. This is over SSH. I'm a flaming idiot.

Comment: The prompt for `sh` and `bash` looks identical on the device, though. I'm used to it having a distinct prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for bash is shipped in the bash-doc tarball. You can view the old versions by downloading the tarball from the [GNU Project Archives](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).

Comment: Thanks, this was surprisingly hard to find.

Comment: @PaulHodges glad the link still works 10 years later!