# Bash process substitution: how to portably refer to standard input?

Tags: bash, process-substitution

The question here is the **bold** sentence below. Suppose I'm trying to do this:

```
diff -u <(some command) {mystery-syntax}
```

I am diffing the output of `some command` and some data that comes from standard input—for instance, a copy-and-paste in the terminal. Like this:

```
$ diff -u <(echo foo) {mystery-syntax}
bar
[Ctrl-D]
--- /dev/fd/63  2021-11-04 11:28:19.360366909 -0700
+++ /dev/fd/62  2021-11-04 11:28:19.360366909 -0700
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foo
+bar
```

What actual syntax is the `{mystery-syntax}` meta-token covering?

The `diff` utility doesn't use the `-` convention for specifying standard input, so we cannot use that.

One answer is: `/dev/fd/0`.

```
$ diff -u <(echo foo) /dev/fd/0
bar
[Ctrl-D]
--- /dev/fd/63  2021-11-04 11:31:02.837040697 -0700
+++ /dev/fd/0   2021-11-04 11:30:56.807964644 -0700
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foo
+bar
```

OK, so we have it working in one way, on systems that have Linux-style `/dev/fd`. **But is there a way without referencing the `/dev` filesystem, which is a system-specific implementation detail?** I believe Bash process substitution is supported on systems which have mechanisms other than `/dev/fd`. The manual states that:

> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes
> (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.

For instance, the obvious:

```
diff <(echo foo) <(cat)
```

doesn't work; for whatever reason, even though the `<(cat)` process substitution needs only the output side of `cat`, `cat` is nevertheless being invoked in such a way that it has no standard input:

```
$ diff -u <(echo foo) <(cat)
cat: -: Input/output error
--- /dev/fd/63  2021-11-04 11:33:59.303347814 -0700
+++ /dev/fd/62  2021-11-04 11:33:59.303347814 -0700  
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-foo
```

> There are some "clever" behaviors here, too. If we explicitly redirect
> `/dev/fd/0` into `cat`'s input, that is still borked somehow:
>
> ```
> $ diff -u <(echo foo) <(cat < /dev/fd/0)
> cat: -: Input/output error
> ```
>
> But! If we give `cat` it a here-document as its standard input, there
> is no interference:
>
> ```
> $ diff -u <(echo foo) <(cat <<<"bar")
> --- /dev/fd/63    2021-11-04 11:40:03.612616179 -0700
> +++ /dev/fd/62    2021-11-04 11:40:03.612616179 -0700
> @@ -1 +1 @@
> -foo
> +bar
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If one of the filenames given to `diff` on the command line is `-` (a dash), the utility will read from standard input in its place.

```bsh
$ echo hello | diff -u <( echo ok ) -
--- /dev/fd/12  Fri Nov 12 21:25:18 2021
+++ -   Fri Nov 12 21:25:18 2021
@@ -1 +1 @@
-ok
+hello
```

From the GNU `diff` manual:

> If  a `FILE` is `-`, read standard input.

From the OpenBSD manual:

> If either `file1` or `file2` is `-`, the standard input is used in its place.

From the POSIX standard:

> `file1`, `file2`
> A pathname of a file to be compared. If either the `file1` or `file2` operand is `-`, the standard input shall be used in its place.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! As you can see, there is a mistaken claim in my question; somehow I came to the conclusion that *"the diff utility doesn't use the - convention"*, but, prompted by your answer, I immediately see that it's actually working fine, in either argument position, opposite to a process-substituted operand.  (There is a bug that `diff - -` assumes that the two arguments are the same object and doesn't read from standard input twice; but that is neither here nor there with regard to this Q&A.)

Comment: Still, I'd like to know the answer for situations when the `-` convention really isn't supported.

Comment: @Kaz Let us know what system you are on where using `diff` with `-` does not work. It's a convention _required_ by the POSIX standard.

Comment: I'm  not sure what I tried; I might have just tried the `diff - -` case and saw that it returns without reading anything. (Why I don't remember is that I wrote this question maybe two weeks ago, and just noticed today that I hadn't finished submitting it, due to getting a warning while closing numerous browser tabs.) So I thought, oh, it's just treating `-` as a file name, and optimizing the case of a file being diffed with itself.

Comment: Ah, OK, I remember now. I was *actually* trying to diff two units of data, both coming from TTY input.

Comment: @Kaz If you're on Linux, try `diff -s - -` and you will see what happens (in short, you are comparing the same data against itself, so there should not be any output).

Comment: @Kaz Consider updating your question if you need to clarify it.

Comment: No, it's pretty clear: how do we feed standard input as a command line argument that a process can open: non-portably in the sense of relying on Bash, but otherwise portably in the sense of simply relying on some `/dev/fd` kernel-specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

`diff -u <(echo foo) <(cat)` doesn't work in an interactive `bash` because commands in process substitution are not put in the foreground so can't read from the terminal device. Like in `cat &` where `cat` is also run in background (not in the foreground process group of the terminal device), the process running `cat` is suspended with a `SIGTTIN` signal as soon as it tries to read from its controlling terminal.

`echo hello | diff -u <(echo ok) <(cat)` works because the whole pipeline made of two subshells is in foreground, and anyway `cat` is reading from the pipe, not the terminal. The process substitutions end up being in foreground because they were started by the subshell (the second component of that pipeline) that is in foreground.

```
bash-5.0$ diff -u <(echo ok) <(ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,args)
--- /dev/fd/63  2021-11-12 22:39:41.985207894 +0000
+++ /dev/fd/62  2021-11-12 22:39:41.985207894 +0000
@@ -1 +1,6 @@
-ok
+    PID    PPID    PGID COMMAND
+   9779    9772    9779 /bin/zsh
+1957388    9779 1957388 bash --norc
+1958861 1957388 1957388 bash --norc
+1958862 1957388 1958862 diff -u /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
+1958863 1958861 1957388 ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,args
```

```
--- /dev/fd/63  2021-11-12 22:39:01.017237420 +0000
+++ /dev/fd/62  2021-11-12 22:39:01.017237420 +0000
@@ -1 +1,7 @@
-ok
+    PID    PPID    PGID COMMAND
+   9779    9772    9779 /bin/zsh
+1957388    9779 1957388 bash --norc
+1958325 1957388 1958324 diff -u /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
+1958326 1958325 1958324 [bash] <defunct>
+1958327 1958325 1958324 bash --norc
+1958328 1958327 1958324 ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,args
```

See how `ps` is running in a different process group in the first case above, and in the same process group as the rest in the second case.

If you run:

```
bash-5.0$ (diff -u <(echo ok) <(ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,args))
--- /dev/fd/63  2021-11-12 22:42:04.761112701 +0000
+++ /dev/fd/62  2021-11-12 22:42:04.761112701 +0000
@@ -1 +1,6 @@
-ok
+    PID    PPID    PGID COMMAND
+1960605    9772 1960605 /bin/zsh
+1960612 1960605 1960612 bash --norc
+1960757 1960612 1960757 diff -u /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
+1960759 1960757 1960757 bash --norc
+1960760 1960759 1960757 ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,args
```

It's back to being OK as then we start a whole subshell in foreground.

So the easy work around here is to run the pipeline in a subshell.

In any case, again, that only applies to interactive shells (where terminal job control is being performed) and when stdin is the controlling terminal of the session.

In scripts (and you generally only care about portability in scripts), there's no problem with `diff -u <(echo ok) <(cat)` even when stdin is a terminal as the shell is non-interactive and doesn't do job control.

That `cat` however does nothing useful, it's the same UUOC as in:

```
cat | diff -u <(echo ok) -
```

Or

```
cat | diff -u <(echo ok) /dev/stdin
```

On systems that don't support `/dev/fd/x` / `/dev/stdin`¹, for commands which unlike `diff`, don't support `-` to specify stdin, `<(cat)` in bash or zsh (but not in ksh versions prior to ksh93u where that feature comes from) uses a temporary named pipe instead, so `diff -u <(echo ok) <(cat)` will still work on those systems.

Since we mention portability though, note that in `zsh`, you need:

```
echo hello | { diff <(echo ok) <(cat); }
```

For the stdin of `cat` to also be the pipe from `echo`.

Also note that:

```
echo hello | cmd /dev/stdin # or /dev/fd/0, /proc/self/fd/0²
```

Doesn't work with ksh93 on Linux, because there, `ksh93`'s `|` uses socketpairs instead of pipes³ and on Linux (and Cygwin), contrary to other systems, opening `/dev/stdin` is not like `dup(0)`, it opens the same file as open on stdin, and you can't `open()` a socket.

More reading in connected Q&As here:

- [What is the portable (POSIX) way to achieve process substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309547)
- [When was process substitution first introduced?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49918)
- [Bash: process substitution and stdin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/153896)

---

<sup>¹ very few these days and there are probably far more systems without `bash` than without `/dev/fd/x`</sup>

<sup>² except for those commands such as `gawk` that treat or can treat `/dev/stdin` as meaning stdin by themselves without actually opening the file in the same was as for `-`.</sup>

<sup>³ as Linux' pipe implementation doesn't let you peek at the contents which ksh93 needs to perform some (dubious) optimisations.</sup>

Comment: > *are not put in the foreground so can't read from the terminal.* Ah, is that what is is? That makes sense because if two or more processes were reading from the TTY, there is no order to it. Simply put scheduler doesn't know that one of the processes is a left argument in a command line and so **its** TTY `read` calls should all wake up first.

Comment: The above observation indicates that the problem is not solvable with processes; the only way Bash could provide platform-independent access to stdin as a file would be to provide some piece of syntax that acts as a macro which expands to `/dev/fd/0` or whatever else. But "whatever else" could not be something that connects to a process, unless it is a special process dedicated to providing the feature: e.g. some "octopus" with multiple pipes which itself reads stdin sequentially and serves it to the pipes in order. Whenever it gets EOF, it closes the current pipe and goes to the next.

Comment: So that is to say, given multiple instances of this magic syntax on a platform without `/dev/fd`, Bash could create a named FIFO for each instance of the syntax, and then have a process which coordinates between standard input and each one of those FIFO's in turn. That process is inserted into the foreground process group so it can have TTY access.

Comment: @Kaz, see edit for clarifications.

Comment: "there are probably far more systems without bash than without /dev/fd/x" well FreeBSD (in the default setup) has `/dev/fd/x` only for x = 0..2 which is not enough to implement process substitution.

Comment: @UncleBilly true. But it's enough here for a portable bash `cmd <(foo) /dev/stdin` that avoids the UUOC.